# Loading DataTable with multiple tables select query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datatable, handler

I never used select queries with multiple tables involved before and now when I do, I'm having troubles with getting the information from the `DataTable`.

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Usergroups], [Groups] 
WHERE [Usergroups.UserID] = @name 
  AND [Groups.GroupID] = [Usergroups.GroupID]
```

And this is how I get the returned values into a DataTable:

```
DataTable groupsTable = new DataTable();
groupsTable.Load(sqlCmd.ExecuteReader());
```

Now, how can I specify my `DataTable` from which table I want to take rows from? For example, this is what I did before multiple tables where involved:

```
string groupName = groupsTable.Rows[0]["Name"];
```

I could not find any resource with such information, but I know it's a basic question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use inner join in sql statement?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The query in your question doesn't produce, as a result, multiple tables.
It produces a JOIN between two tables.

As a consequence, on the C# side, you don't have two tables but just one as before, with the all fields from both tables.

As a side note, a better way to JOIN tables together is through the use of the JOIN statement like this

```
SELECT *  -- a field list is better here ---
FROM Usergroups ug INNER JOIN Groups g ON g.GroupID=ug.GroupID
WHERE ug.UserID=@name
```

and you should add, to the SELECT clause, a list of the fields that you are really interested in.

[SEE a simple JOIN reference](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

If you want to retrieve the values of the two tables in separate DataTable objects, then you need to use a DataSet in this way

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dtUserGroups = new DataTable("UserGroups");
DataTable dtGroups = new DataTable("Groups");
ds.Tables.Add(dtUserGroups );
ds.Tables.Add(dtGroups);
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UserGroups;SELECT * from Groups", con))
{
    using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        ds.Load(dr, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, dtUserGroups, dtGroups);

        // Now you have the two tables filled and 
        // you can read from them in the usual way

    }
}
```

This last example could further enhanced adding a [DataRelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object to the DataSet to represent the relationship between the two tables. This could allow your code to navigate the parent/child recordset.

Answer (score 4):

You may try in this way :

```
string query = "SELECT U.ID,U.NAME, C.NAME AS CUSTOMERNAME, C.DOB FROM USER U INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C ON U.ID = C.USERID"
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
```

Above code will return you one DataTable with data from two different tables say "User" and "Customer".

I hope now you know how to access data from a DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `JOIN` for combining multiple tables such as [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp), [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp), [RIGHT OUTER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp), [FULL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) as per your requirements. So, when you use `INNER JOIN`, it will have the columns of two joined tables, i.e., if

> `tblA` has **a, b,c** as columns and
>
> `tblB` has **a, e,f** as columns

***then the inner joined table will have a, b, c, e, f as its columns.***

Then, you can use like this:

```
public DataTable LoadData()
    {
        DataTable dataTable;
        string connString = @"your connection string here";
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Usergroups t1 INNER JOIN Groups t2 ON t2.GroupID=t1.GroupID WHERE t1.UserID=@name";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);        
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();

        // create data adapter
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
        da.Fill(dataTable);
        conn.Close();
        return dataTable;
    }
```

After Getting the `DataTable`, then you can use this table like:

```
DataTable dt = LoadDataClass.LoadData(); 
string groupName = dt.Rows[0]["Name"];  //For first row
```

I hope you get it.

Answer (score 0):

in wpf c#, this method can also be used to retrieve data from multiple tables

```
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_pageDataBase.connectionString()))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    SqlDataAdapter Usergroups= new SqlDataAdapter("select *from Usergroups", conn);
                    Usergroups.Fill(dt);

                    SqlDataAdapter Groups= new SqlDataAdapter("select *from Groups", conn);
                    Groups.Fill(dt);

                    datagridName.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;      

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```